# Can I save regex state for next input?

Tags: regex, haskell, finite-automata

I parse TCP packets with some data and this data can divided in several packets. I can't save packets, so after passing first packet I can't read it again. I need to know if there is my pattern in data, when, for example, first packet contains "hello wo" and second contains "rld!" and I want to know if there is the "world" in sequence.

For simply example, I have two files and I can search in them:

```
-- file: Seq.hs
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import System.Environment

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    inpStr1 <- readFile (args !! 0)
    putStrLn $ show (inpStr1 =~ "foo" :: Bool)
    inpStr2 <- readFile (args !! 1)
    putStrLn $ show (inpStr2 =~ "foo" :: Bool)
```

Can I save state of FA after processing inpStr1 to continue searching with inpStr2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of regular expressions I'd suggest you to use [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec). It's fast, robust and allows [incremental input](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#g:2):

> A fast parser combinator library, aimed particularly at dealing efficiently with network protocols and complicated text/binary file formats.

Regular expressions get ugly easily and in particular in Haskell, using a typed combinator parsing library makes things much clearer.

There is also package [network-attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-attoparsec):

> Utility functions for running a parser against a socket, without the need of a bigger framework such as Pipes or Conduit.

Comment: Roman Cheplyaka's been working on that! See `regex-applicative`. I know he hasn't gotten the performance where he wants it yet, and the interface is a bit limited, but if you really just want to parse a regular language, it offers a really pretty way to do it.

Comment: There is the note to attoparsec:
Note:incremental input does not imply that attoparsec will release portions of its internal state for garbage collection as it proceeds.Its internal representation is equivalent to a single ByteString:if you feed incremental input to a parser, it will require memory proportional to the amount of input you supply.(This is necessary to support arbitrary backtracking)
It is not good for me, because it can be large input, divided in small packets and can't  save it all.
I think regex uses backtracking,too,so in my issue better case is some FA like aho-corasick.